# req.user losing data after jwt refresh

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization

First let me provide all the relevant code then I will explain my issue

my middleware to authenticate jwt

```js
module.exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ success: false, msg: "not authorized" });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ success: false, msg: "jwt cannot be verified" });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

my code that generates access and refresh tokens

```js
module.exports.generateAccessToken = (user) => {
  const payload = {
    sub: user._id,
    name: user.username,
  };

  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "20s",
  });
};

module.exports.generateRefreshToken = (user) => {
  const payload = {
    sub: user._id,
    name: user.username,
  };

  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
}
```

this is what happens when a user logs in (im storing refresh tokens in an array rn I will change that when I get all this to work properly)

```js
module.exports.postAuthLogin = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ success: false, msg: "Invalid username" });
    }

    const passwordIsValid = validatePasswordHash(
      password,
      user.salt,
      user.hash
    );

    if (!passwordIsValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ success: false, msg: "Invalid password" });
    }

    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
    const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user);

    refreshTokens.push(refreshToken);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, accessToken, refreshToken });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.json({ msg: err.toString() });
  }
};
```

finally this is what runs when a user makes a request to refresh there token

```js
module.exports.postAuthRefreshToken = (req, res) => {
  const { refreshToken } = req.body;

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, msg: "must provide a refresh token" });
  }

  if (!refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      success: false,
      msg: "refresh token was deleted you must login again",
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, accessToken });
  });
};
```

so my issue is initially when I login and get my refresh and access token, then I request a route that is protected with the authenticateToken middleware my req.user in that route looks something like this

```js
{
  sub: '5ff5f16f4203ade4d1b63da8',
  name: 'test1',
  iat: 1610055109,
  exp: 1610055129
}
```

but when my token expires and I request a new one it does get verified and im able to access the protected route BUT my req.user looks like this

```js
{ iat: 1610055143, exp: 1610055163 }
```

I have been banging my head against the wall with this problem for a little while now so any help would be more then appreciated and if you need anymore info just say something and ill 100% provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, accessToken });
  });
```

The "user" is actually going to be the decoded payload

```
{
  sub: '5ff5f16f4203ade4d1b63da8',
  name: 'test1',
  iat: 1610055109,
  exp: 1610055129
}
```

which you then pass to the the generateAccessToken and try to access the fields _id & username of it which are undefined.

You can either change the payload fields to be

```
{
  _id: '5ff5f16f4203ade4d1b63da8',
  username: 'test1',
  iat: 1610055109,
  exp: 1610055129
}
```

so when passing the decoded payload it will still have same field names.
Or you can fetch the user from DB again using the payload.sub and then pass the user to the generateAccessToken.

Comment: OHHHHH, I see thank you for some reason when I saw user I immediately thought that for some reason it would have all the normal fields my user should have. I will refactor that but thanks